# Profiling Node.js web application on Linux

Tags: node.js, profiling

Which would be the best option to profile a Node.js application on linux? I tried https://github.com/c4milo/node-webkit-agent and https://github.com/baryshev/look (this is based on nodetime), but they both seem pretty experimental. What surprises me the most is that the results reported by these tools are different.

The major disadvantages for look are that the heap snapshots aren't very relevant and you can't CPU profile for more than 1 minute.

With node-webkit-agent the Chrome browser is running out of memory.

I'm doing profiling while sending requests using JMeter to my web application.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're willing to use an online service instead of a module, but you could give http://nodefly.com/ a try, it's free and has worked quite good for me.